# Drupal sections division

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I'm doing an intranet for a company that has multiple projects going on internally.

The idea is that each project has only 3 distintive things: its homepage, a small theme variation and its posts. Everything else is shared: every user can post into every section, it's just a way of visually dividing information.

Each project will have a path:

[...].com/projects/project1
[...].com/projects/project2
[...].com/projects/project3
My initial idea is the only 2 content types to have an extra (select type) field which is SECTION. Then, I make a .tpl for each homepage with the variations and calling the views that filter posts by this SECTION field.

This would would work but I'm missing 2 aspects: will I be able to use the section field value in the path auto module? Say I post a node with "corporate" as SECTION value. Will I be able to make it to [...].com/projects/corporate/post-title ?

Second issue is I don't know how to make [...].com/projects/corporate/post-title to load the theme for the "corporate" SECTION

Is my SECTION field approach right or is there a better solution? If anyone know an answer here or article somewhere that addresses this scenario please just point me to it.

Comment: yes you can use cck value in path auto and secondly you don't need to create multiple projects, use the http://drupal.org/project/themekey module.

Answer (score 0):

Organic groups may be somewhat of an overkill but it could work http://drupal.org/project/og